# Custom Expression as parameter and returning IEnumerable of generic type

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I am trying to create an extension method that "extends" on an `IEnumerable` of a type, accepts an expression as a parameter and returns an `IEnumerable` of the same type.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CustomExtension<T>(this IEnumerable<T> cities, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Enumerable.Where(cities, predicate);   
    //the line above is wrong, doesn't compile, but it explains my intentions...        
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
var bigCities = cities.CustomExtension(c => c.occupants >= 1000000);
```

OR

```
var coldCities = cities.CustomExtension(c => c.avgTemp <= 20);
```

**NOTE:** It isn't just for "city" objects, the plan is to keep it generic so I can use the same method on similar types

Thanks in advance...

Comment: So what's wrong with just using `Where`? Also your example should be `cities.Where(predicate)`.

Comment: You are basically describing the `Where` extension method.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of this extension. I ask because currently the functionality you describe already exists. Is there some additional goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidG - Doesn't the expression need to be compiled in order to be used as a predicate for `Where`? I was under the impression that only `IQueryable` used `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` for predicates.

Comment: @TravisJ Good spot! In that case it should be `cities.Where(predicate.Compile())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CustomExtension<T>(this IEnumerable<T> cities, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return cities.Where(x => predicate(x));
    }
```

Comment: So what does this do that above simply using `Where`?

Comment: Hey, I just answer the questions.

Comment: Then I suggest you answer something useful instead :)

Comment: Also your code is wrong, see my comment on the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change Expression<Func<T>, bool>> to just Func<T, bool>. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Basically, if you want to pass in a predefined condition to the extension, use Func<T, bool>  as the parameter type, and then you can manipulate the data however you want, and this is all generic.

Comment: But OP is asking about an Expression, not a Func, they are not the same thing.

Comment: The way the OP was using the Expression type appears more in concert with how the Func type was designed to be used.

Comment: Not necessarily, for example `IQueryable` takes an expression.

Comment: This is sounding less like an isolated IQueryable instance, and more like a Linq Where clause.

Comment: That is to say, IEnumerable will be invoking this method call.